# How can I obtain the 95% confidence interval for the variance of a random effect?

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, variance, random-variable

After running a linear mixed model, I want to obtain the 95% confidence interval for the variance estimation of my random effect. The function `confint()` in R gives me the 95% CI of the standard deviation of the random effect. Can I square the lower and upper limits to get obtain the 95% CI for the variance?

Comment: Why do you doubt if you can do this?

Comment: This sort of question seems common. Is there a standard reference (or answer on this site) to point to for the general idea of "order statistics can be passed through a monotonic transform, expectations cannot"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you do.

However, do bear in mind that the sampling distribution of random effects is in general highly asymmetric, so ensure that you use the default profile confidence intervals -  as the others (for example Wald) may not be very reliable. Another method would be to use a bootstrap approach.

Comment: `confint()` uses profile likelihood by default (*not* Wald intervals), so asymmetry is not a problem.  Bootstrap *might* be better, but the first (correct) clause in your answer doesn't necessarily imply the rest of your answer.

Comment: @BenBolker thank you, I was not aware that they were profiled by default. I have updated the answer to reflect this.